# NullPointerException in a Mock Test

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

I am a beginner and I need your help, please!

I have this class :

```
public class MyClass {
    private IService1 service1;
    private IService2 service2;

    public void setService1(final IService1 service1) {
        this.service1 = service1;
    }

    public MyList myMethod(final Param param) throws MyException {
        final MyList list = method2(param);
        if (list.isEmpty()) {      //here it throws a null pointer exception, because the mock didn't return "list" from my test
            throw new MyException("Blablabla");
        }
        return list;
    }
```

And the param has a Collection myObjList, and 2 two list, list1 and list2.

Here is what method2 does :

```
private MyList method2(final Param param) {
    Collection<MyObj> myObjList = CollectionUtils.isEmpty(param.getMyObjList) ? list1 : list2;
    MyList list = new MyList(new HashSet<>(myObjList), false);
    return service1.filter(list, param);    
}
```

I made a test and mocked service1, but I have a nullPointerException and I don't understand why.

Here is the test :

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyClassTest {
    @InjectMocks
    private  MyClass myClass;

    @Mock
    private IService1 service1;

    @Test
    public void test() throws MyException {
        //Given
        Param param = create_param(); //this is OK
        MyList list = new MyList();
        list.add("something");
        when(service1.filter(any(), any())).thenReturn(list); //doesn't return list

        //When
        MyList myObjList = myClass.method(param);

        //Then
        assertThat(myObjList).isNotNull();
        assertThat(myObjList.size()).isEqualTo(1);
    }
```

Could you please help me to understand my mistake?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well the most obvious check is: when you tried debugging it, was `service1` null? If so, you know the problem is no longer the exception, but that `service1` wasn't being populated. It would help if you'd provide a [mcve] - note that it should be absolutely minimal. There's probably no need for `MyClass`, and your interface method can probably be just a `void` method with no parameters...

Comment: Do you have `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` on your test class?

Comment: (Or anything else that will inject the mocks. This is why a complete example is important...)

Comment: Also, your `MyClass` doesn't appear to have any way of injecting the service at the moment... you haven't shown a constructor or a setter.

Comment: Post Updated, thanks